# Google Chrome background-gradient

Tags: css, google-chrome, linear-gradients

Really amateur question here - body background-gradient isn't working in chrome, very strange, I've tried:

```
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 bottom, from(#FFF), to(#000));
```

And

```
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0%, 0%, 0%, 100%, from(#fff), to(#000));
```

And

```
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, center top, center bottom, from(#fff), to(#000));
```

All to no avail! Works in every other browser...

Comment: Here is Ultimate Gradient Generator works really well, and fixes compatibility for all browsers
http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#917c4d, #ffffff);
```

WebKit updated to match the spec syntax, so you should [have this to get maximum browser support](http://jsfiddle.net/robertc/bxTXd/):

```
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, center top, center bottom, from(#917c4d), to(#ffffff));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#917c4d, #ffffff);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(#917c4d, #ffffff);
background: -o-linear-gradient(#917c4d, #ffffff);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(#917c4d, #ffffff);
background: linear-gradient(#917c4d, #ffffff);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers guys, however the culprit was a missing clearfix meaning body's height was 0. However I will use your posts for reference and for this project! Robertc - thanks for putting in the effort of doing that for me!

Comment: **For IE :** `filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#917c4d', endColorstr='#ffffff');` [More info here.](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/cross-browser-css-gradient)

Answer (score 3):

CSS3 linear-gradient tag is now supported by all major browsers.

The syntax requires an additional `to`. Therefore instead of e.g. `center top`, `left top` etc use e.g. `to top` like

```
background-image: linear-gradient(to top , #094F86, #4EABDB);
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this:

```
<style>
.myawesomegradient{
background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,#ffffff), color-stop(100%,#000000));
}
</style>
```

Should work in Safari and Chrome ...

Answer (score -1):

Like you, I had a problem with the Chrome browser, but the only solution is to use inline styles! style = "" Write the your code here to solve the problem